# WooCommerce Filter: Sale Percent Off

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a single PHP function that I can insert into my functions.php file in Wordpress (Using WooCommerce plugin, Storefront Theme). I have found two pieces of code online that separately each do a part of what I am trying to achieve but I don't know how to combine them together. Just a disclaimer I don't know how to read or write PHP very well.

Hopefully this image helps clear up what I am trying to achieve. The left represents what the page looks like using just the first piece of code, the right represents how I want the page to look when both pieces of code are combined:
[image: Before/After Filter]

The first piece of code seen below correctly takes a products regular price and its sale price, and then calculates the discount that a customer would receive. The end result is a string that says e.g. "22% OFF". The problem is that this string is inserted after the price is displayed and not in the sale banner itself.

```
function woocommerce_saved_sales_price( $price, $product ) {
$percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
return $price . sprintf( __('%s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '% OFF' );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'woocommerce_saved_sales_price', 10, 2 );
```

The second piece of code actually edits the sale banner I am trying to change but I don't know how to get it to include the calculated discount that the other filter achieves.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'wc_custom_replace_sale_text' );
function wc_custom_replace_sale_text( $html ) {
return str_replace( __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'SALE! [INSERT % OFF OUTPUT HERE]', 'woocommerce' ), $html );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second piece of code should be

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'wc_custom_replace_sale_text' );
function wc_custom_replace_sale_text( $html ) {
  global $product;
  //$product = wc_get_product( $product->get_id() );
  $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100 );
  return str_replace( __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ), __( 'SALE! ', 'woocommerce' ).$percentage.'% OFF', $html );
}
```

Tested and worked

Comment: Can confirm this works. Fantastic job, much appreciated!

Comment: Good luck my friend :D